# Cheese screen black with good webcam under CentOS Stream

Tags: centos, drivers, video, images, camera

I have a webcam that works like a charm when connected to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS:

```
$ uname -r
5.11.0-7614-generic

$ sudo hwinfo | less
...
24: USB 00.0: 0000 Unclassified device
  [Created at usb.122]
  Unique ID: cLrx.dV4P5TUBBt9
  Parent ID: k4bc.uFSp9Drkgd7
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0c.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0
  SysFS BusID: 1-2:1.0
  Hardware Class: unknown
  Model: "Chicony Electronics Chicony USB2.0 Camera"
  Hotplug: USB
  Vendor: usb 0x04f2 "Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd"
  Device: usb 0xb685 "Chicony USB2.0 Camera"
  Revision: "54.04"
  Driver: "uvcvideo"
  Driver Modules: "uvcvideo"
  Device File: /dev/input/event7
  Device Number: char 13:71
  Speed: 480 Mbps
  Module Alias: "usb:v04F2pB685d5404dcEFdsc02dp01ic0Eisc01ip00in00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: uvcvideo is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe uvcvideo"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #26 (Hub)
...

$ v4l2-ctl --list-devices
Chicony USB2.0 Camera: Chicony  (usb-0000:00:0c.0-2):
    /dev/video0
    /dev/video1

$ apt list --installed | grep cheese

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

cheese-common/focal-updates,focal-updates,now 3.34.0-1ubuntu1 all [zainstalowany,automatycznie]
cheese/focal-updates,now 3.34.0-1ubuntu1 amd64 [zainstalowany]
libcheese-gtk25/focal-updates,now 3.34.0-1ubuntu1 amd64 [zainstalowany,automatycznie]
libcheese8/focal-updates,now 3.34.0-1ubuntu1 amd64 [zainstalowany,automatycznie]
```

However in CentOS Stream Cheese shows only black screen, even though the CentOS seems to recognize the camera:

```
$ uname -r
4.18.0-301.1.el8.x86_64

$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:b685 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 

$ dmesg
...
[  133.699457] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[  134.170286] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=04f2, idProduct=b685, bcdDevice=54.04
[  134.170291] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[  134.170295] usb 1-1: Product: Chicony USB2.0 Camera
[  134.170298] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Sonix Technology Co., Ltd.
[  134.179543] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Chicony USB2.0 Camera (04f2:b685)
[  134.229062] input: Chicony USB2.0 Camera: Chicony  as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0b.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/input/input10

$ sudo lshw | less
...
              *-usb
                   description: Video
                   product: Chicony USB2.0 Camera: Chicony
                   vendor: Sonix Technology Co., Ltd.
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@1:1
                   logical name: input8
                   logical name: /dev/input/event7
                   version: 54.04
                   capabilities: usb-2.00 usb
                   configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
...

$ dnf list installed | grep cheese
cheese.x86_64                                      2:3.28.0-3.el8                                @AppStream
cheese-libs.x86_64                                 2:3.28.0-3.el8                                @AppStream
```

Please note that with no camera connected Cheese displays "No device found" message, so apparently webcam works and is recognized by Cheese, but something breaks down afterwards.

In Ubuntu Wiki I found a suggestion to install guvcview to better diagnose what's going on with the camera and under Unbuntu in fact it shows far more cfg details than Cheese. However guvcview is not available in default CentOS repos:

```
$ sudo dnf install guvcview
[sudo] password for admin: 
Last metadata expiration check: 10:08:52 ago on Sat 15 May 2021 10:19:51 CEST.
No match for argument: guvcview
Error: Unable to find a match: guvcview
```

Apparently CentOS is using far older app versions. No wonder, as it is a conservative distribution. I cannot however believe that it would be so old that webcams would not be working. Ages ago exactly the same camera was working with ancient Ubuntu 16 with kernel v4 so I just need tweak the cfg.

How to make it work?

Comment: Are you using the same version of kernel, drivers and cheese on both systems?

Comment: Nope. I've added kernel version above.

Comment: You only posted kernel version. Anyway, even if `uname -r` reports the same version it doesn't mean that the same kernel is used - distro maintainers apply various patches, use different configs, use different firmware.

Comment: I perfectly understand. How can better diagnose which exactly drivers I am using in both cases?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk looks like in both cases exactly the same driver (uvcvideo) is used at exactly the same version (54.04)